# How to make selected icon in tab bar "shiny" despite using [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:SomeCustomImage];

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar

Actually it's shiny by default. However, many of my tab bars do not have shiny icon.

I wonder what did I do wrong that it fails to be shiny?

I look around and I saw that a way to eliminate the shiny glossy image is by doing

[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:SomeCustomImage];

That's what happen. I use custom selector image. Well, what about if I still want that custom selector image and I still want the shiny look?

[image]

I look at the code and see no difference.

I set image tint to default and it's still not shiny.

Note: I figured out the problem

The other tab bars use custom selected image

[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:SomeCustomImage];

That removes the gloss.

Well, how do I use setSelectionIndicatorImage and yet maintain shiny glossy look.

Comment: Without seeing any of the code you've used, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: The blue tab bar at the top is a standard one with tint colour. The one at the bottom is a custom one(the default one does not support more than 4 tabs).